# What is the purpose of "Variant" LMKs?

Tags: hsm

What is the purpose of "Variant" LMKs?

The JPOS project (http://jpos.org/wiki/HSM_basics) gives this description:

> To make things more secure HSM's use variants. A variant is a hex
>   value for each type of key.

**Q1)** How do variants make things more secure?

**Q2)** Is increased security the only reason why variant's are used?  I thought another reasons for Variants was to increase the number of keys without requiring more memory storage in the HSM?

Answer (score 1):

In some HSMs certain kinds of keys have certain commands possible on them, for example you would not be able to use a PIN key to decrypt the value.

I'm not sure if this relates to the jPOS use case: https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/main/java/org/jpos/security/jceadapter/JCESecurityModule.java#L1820

I'd like to know too